# Error when bind values into a nested object

Tags: angularjs

Problem when binding values into a nested object

I want to add data to the following object structure.

```
Company {
    stat {
        internalData {
            value = 35
        }
    }

}
```

I have used the below code

```
Company.stat.internalData["value"] = 35;
```

When I used the above code I got the error as  internalData is undefined.
Could someone kindly help me. Thanks inadvance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you have already created the following object:

```
let Company = {
    stat: {

    }
}
```

As you can see, `internalData` is sure not defined. You can't access it's fields using `internalData["value"]`. You need to create it first like this:

```
Company.stat.internalData = {};
```

And then define its property called `value`:

```
Company.stat.internalData["value"] = 35;
```

`Company.stat.internalData.value = 35;` would work too.

Or, you can create the entire object with just one expression:

```
let Company = {
    stat: {
        internalData: {
            value: 35
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Issue here is you are trying to access the property before the object Company is defined. So you need to define something like this before setting the value,

```
Company = {};
Company.stat = {};
Company.stat.internalData["value"] = 35;
```